# onTokenRefereshed() method is not called on Nexus 7 API level 18 android version 4.3

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nexus-7

I am using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) in my project. This is done by following documentation. It works nice on android version 4.4 and above. But I get the null value using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` after installing and clearing data on Nexus 7 with android version 4.3. It seems like `onTokenRefresh()` is not called and token is not generated. That's why I'm asking this question. I also check for Google Play services to ensure it has the updated version by this method.

```
public static boolean checkGooglePlayService(Activity context) {

        final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(context, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```